# I can't log in to Marketplace

Tags: nokia-lumia-800

I've had problems with my Lumia 800. I could log in with my live ID, its already synchronized, but when I try marketplace, it asks me to log in again and it says Error. What could the problem be?

Comment: Check if the account is **synchronized**, See if Time, Date & Region are all correct.

Comment: Did you manage to download anything no marketplace? My friend is having same problem with windows phone 7.8.

Comment: It seemed to be synchronized, but still couldnt actually log in when i got into Marketplace. Each time I tried to download something, it asked me to log in and it says there was an error logging in all the time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, im using Nokia lumia 800. I have managed to download one or two apps Inbetween it playing up, but they were rubbish that I was testing while trying to fix the problem. I think this fault is all on the servers. I hope they are aware and trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Ram Ray was correct, it is a time issue. The phone must have exactly the actual time from ms servers (set it mannualy from windows clock synced with ntp). And go to auto = problem fixed:)